# Можно ли подключиться к локальному среверу удаленно?

Tags: php, веб-сервер, xampp

Допустим, есть разработанный сайт на ПК-1. На ПК-1 установлен локальный сервер XAMPP. Можно ли с ПК-2 подключиться к этому сайту удаленно без залива сайта на хостинг?

Comment: https://ngrok.com/

Comment: также можно, если ПК-1 и ПК-2 подключены к одной локальной сети

Comment: И даже не в одной локальной сети можно.

Answer (score 0):

Можно.
Но всё зависит от настроек.
Если у вас локальная сеть между компьютерами то достаточно будет настроить ваш сервер на прослушивание трафика в локальной сети а не только на локальной машине, за это отвечает строка из конфигурации апач Listen [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:{yy} где [] - ip для прослушивания а {} - порт для прослушивания, достаточно выставить Listen {YY}, чтобы прослушивать все адреса на порту YY.
Если ПК не в пределах одной сети - необходимо воспользоватся одним из способов публикации, без внешнего сервера не обойтись, но серверов публикации много и есть бесплатные ( в комментарии под вашим вопросом вам один такой советовали).
Так же возможен вариант превращения вашего ПК в публичный сервер, для этого у вас должен быть "белый" айпи адрес, эта услуга предоставляется некоторыми операторами.